# Duplicate rows according to column attribute

Tags: awk

Using a csv file, I need to generate a file like the output desired, the purpose is using the column 3 duplicate columns 1 and 2 accoording to the times in column 3 the separation is ). example

```
39823,39828:38466-38896/2(1-216)
39840:38466-38896/2(217-432)
39852:38466-38896/2(433-648)
```

in column 3 there is 3 times ( ... ) then, should be 3 times duplicate for columns 1 and 2.

Here the input file

```
21,39823,39828:38466-38896/2(1-216) 39840:38466-38896/2(217-432) 39852:38466-38896/2(433-648),0
22,39827,39828:38466-38896/2(1-216) 39840:38466-38896/2(217-432) 39852:38466-38896/2(433-648) 39864:38466-38896/2(649-864),0
23,39825,39828:38466-38896/2(1-216) 39840:38466-38896/2(217-432) 39852:38466-38896/2(433-648), 39852:38000-90000/2(433-648)
24,39827,39828:38466-39196/2(1-366) 39840:38466-39196/2(367-732) 39852:38466-39196/2(733-1098),0
```

Output desired

```
21  39823   39828:38466-38896/2(1-216)
21  39823   39840:38466-38896/2(217-432)
21  39823   39852:38466-38896/2(433-648)
22  39827   39828:38466-38896/2(1-216)
22  39827   39840:38466-38896/2(217-432)
22  39827   39852:38466-38896/2(433-648)
22  39827   39864:38466-38896/2(649-864)
23  39825   39828:38466-38896/2(1-216)
23  39825   39840:38466-38896/2(217-432)
23  39825   39852:38466-38896/2(433-648)
**23  39825   39852:38000-90000/2(433-648)**
24  39827   39828:38466-39196/2(1-366)
24  39827   39840:38466-39196/2(367-732)
24  39827   39852:38466-39196/2(733-1098)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looking at the data, you have comma separated values that should account for columns 1 and 2, which would be retained variables (will loop).  If you do character by character, you have spaces and for each space you want a new line item in column 3 with columns 1 and 2 duplicated.  Once you reach the end of the line, you move to the next line and redefine your variables.

Comment: @OXXO, kindly do add always in your post what you have tried yourself too, as we all are here to learn, cheers.

Comment: @OXXO, also try to select answers(after sometime when there are few answers to question) as correct answer to make the post complete, cheers.

Comment: Well noted all advices, tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -v s1="**" -F' |,' '{nf=$NF==0||!$NF?NF-1:NF;for(i=3;i<=nf;i++){if($i){match($i,/\(.*\)/);val=substr($i,RSTART,RLENGTH);printf("%s%s",++a[val]>3? s1 $1 OFS $2 OFS $i s1:$1 OFS $2 OFS $i,ORS)}}}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -v s1="**" -F' |,' '
{
  nf=$NF==0||!$NF?NF-1:NF;
  for(i=3;i<=nf;i++){
     if($i){
       match($i,/\(.*\)/);
       val=substr($i,RSTART,RLENGTH);
       printf("%s%s",++a[val]>3? s1 $1 OFS $2 OFS $i s1:$1 OFS $2 OFS $i,ORS)
     }
  }
}'   Input_file
```

Comment: RavinderSingh13, your code works perfect, I remove the variable s1="**"  as this is not necessary in the case of data in column 4.

Comment: @OXXO. cool, glad that it helped you. Cheers and enjoy learning and sharing knowledge.

Comment: RavinderSingh13, Thanks for helping and sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk -F',|[[:space:]]+' '{ for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) print $1, $2, $i }' OFS='\t' file
```

The output:

```
21  39823   39828:38466-38896/2(1-216)
21  39823   39840:38466-38896/2(217-432)
21  39823   39852:38466-38896/2(433-648)
22  39827   39828:38466-38896/2(1-216)
22  39827   39840:38466-38896/2(217-432)
22  39827   39852:38466-38896/2(433-648)
22  39827   39864:38466-38896/2(649-864)
23  39825   39828:38466-38896/2(1-216)
23  39825   39840:38466-38896/2(217-432)
23  39825   39852:38466-38896/2(433-648)
24  39827   39828:38466-39196/2(1-366)
24  39827   39840:38466-39196/2(367-732)
24  39827   39852:38466-39196/2(733-1098)
```

Comment: RomanPerekhrest, it works perfectly tks. Kindly can you addapt the code to the edited input file, i have added an extra column it should be 0 all time, but when there is values in this column, then I need to get a new row with information, as in the new output file. appreciate your help.

Comment: RomanPerekhrest, also, please can you explain a litte the part of |[[:space:]]+ in your code. how it works to separate the columns, tks

Comment: @OXXO, should `0` always come as the last value in each record? Should those asterisks appear in your new output `**23 ...`?

Comment: RomanPerekhrest, yes in column 4 the value 0 will be always, but in some cases data as the last updated example. And for the ** no needed it comes automatic when i select the option bold :).

Comment: RomanPerekhrest, I try to use your code also, but for some reason i got in the output the same information of input data?.

Comment: @OXXO, you have already accepted the answer meaning that it solved your issue. Additional questions are unnecessary.